# Multi-page Multi-Model Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, models, one-to-many, multipage

I'm trying to create a multi-page form that uses multiple models. I have an applicant and this applicant has more than one address (one to many relationship).

I would like the first page to contain information about the applicant, and then the page after that to have the form for the address(es)

This is what I have at the moment:

applicant.rb

```
has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy     
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

address.rb

```
belongs_to :applicant
```

applicants_controller.rb:

```
def new
  session[:applicant_params] ||= {}

  @applicant = Applicant.new(session[:applicant_params])
  2.times do
    @addresses=@applicant.addresses.build
  end

  session[:address_params] = @addresses.attributes

end

def create

  session[:applicant_params].deep_merge!(params[:applicant]) if params[:applicant]
  session[:address_params] ||= params[:address]
  @applicant = Applicant.new( session[:applicant_params] )
  @applicant.addresses.new(session[:address_params])



  if params[:forward_button] or params[:back_button]


    @applicant.current_step = session[:applicant_step] 

  if params[:back_button]
    @applicant.previous_step  
  else
    @applicant.next_step
  end

  session[:applicant_step]=@applicant.current_step

  render "new"

else

.....
```

In the new view:

```
<%= form_for @applicant do |f| %>

  <%= render "#{@applicant.current_step}_step", :f => f %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Continue", :name => "forward_button" unless @applicant.last_step? %> </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Back", :name => "back_button" unless @applicant.first_step? %></p>


<% end %>
```

@applicant.current_step will be either address_step or applicant_step, and these are below:

_applicant_step.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :first_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name ,:width=>'10px', :size=>"20", :maxlength=>"20" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :middle_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
</div>
....
```

_address_step.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |u| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= u.label :address %><br />
    <%= u.text_area :address , :cols=> 20, :rows=>5%>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= u.label :telephone, "Telephone Number" %><br />
    <%=  u.text_field :telephone %>
</div>
...
```

And that's it. Now the problem I have is as follows, I want to save the address information as well as the applicant information. And I thought just by saying: @applicant.addresses.new then they will be included in the session information of the applicant, but they weren't (when I got the the address page, there were no fields!). So I created a new session variable to hold the address information. But I have a problem. Everytime I go from one page to the other (in the create action) a new address field (with all its attributes) is created and added to the form. So first I have one address, then I have 2 and so on. Am I going about this the wrong way? How can I have a multi-page form, with multiple models (that are related), and when going from one page to the next the data is not erased.. Until I eventually reach the last page where I could submit (and save) all the models..

I would be grateful if anyone could help..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly get this working, but (depending on the number of steps you need), it could get pretty convoluted.

Have you considered using a single `new` and `create` request on the server side, and using Javascript to break up the form into multiple steps on the client side? It seems like this could be a lot simpler. Your Rails application will behave more like a standard REST application, and you can break this up however you see fit on the client side.

I have not used it myself, but a jQuery plugin such as this one should do the trick:
http://thecodemine.org/

Comment: I haven't tried a jquery solution, thank you for the link. I was hoping to find a solution that would work on my existing code, because I feel I'm getting close.. so it would be great if anyone could help me fix it somehow.. thanks again..