# In Rails, how can I search or create parent model when creating a new child model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Rails, so I was wondering what the convention is something like this. I have 2 models, `Assignment` and `Task` with has_many/belongs_to relation. I want users to be able to create a `Task` model, through searching for a `Assignment` model or creating a new one. So my flow is:

1. User tries to create new `Task`
2. User asked to input `Assignment` name
3. Search through database for `Assignment`

   a. If a `Assignment` is found, show details, ask user to confirm

   b. If not found, ask user to create a new `Assignment`
4. With `Assignment` attached, ask user to input `Task` details

What I was wondering is, should all this be handled under `TaskController (task#new)` or should step #3 be separately handled under `AssignmentController (assignment#search)`? Also, where/when should I save the `Assignment` model, after step #3 or wait until user goes through step #4 (so there are no assignments without tasks)?

Note: Users wouldn't be able to create `Parent` model by itself, if this makes any difference.

The closest SO question I've found related to this issue is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445893/multi-page-multi-model-form-in-rails?rq=1) but there's no answer. Or is JS really the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT: Relationship clarification**

Parent is "Assignment" and Child is "Task" (renamed all "Parent" and "Child" references above). I want users to be able to list all assignments and list all tasks, but only create Task (no Assignment should exist without a Task attached to it). Tasks also belongs to Users. So User will create a Task that belongs to himself, and an Assignment (existing or new).

Currently, my `routes.rb` looks like:

```
resources :assignments
resources :tasks
```

**EDIT: Models**

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assignment
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more insight into the nature of these parent/child models, i.e. what they represent? Sometimes tweaking a relationship slightly can suddenly give you a more natural and less painful flow.

Comment: @janfoeh, edited question above, not sure if it's clear enough.

Comment: Thanks! That does help. What does an `Assignment` do? If Tasks cannot be without Assignments and vice versa, that sounds like a job for a join model and `has_many :through`.

Comment: @janfoeh not sure what you mean by "What does an `Assignment` do?" It's just a Model that holds the common information for Tasks (name, description, type, etc), while a Task is specific to each User. If I understand what you meant correctly, a `Task` should be the join model of `Assignment` and `User`?

Comment: I would have expected it to be the other way around - `Task` describes what to do ("clean the living room"), and `Assignment` describing who owns that task. Doesn't that make more sense?

Comment: In that case, `Assignment` would be a simple join model: `Assignment belongs_to :user ; belongs_to :task` - `User has_many :assignments ; has_many :tasks, through: :assignments` - `Task has_one :assignment; has_one :user, through: :assignment`

Comment: @janfoeh Hmm it is the other way around, but I think that's easily fixable. I added my models and relationships above, to be clearer. Is what I wanted to achieve feasible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70912/discussion-between-janfoeh-and-dee).